# Why host.json not being copied to output in F# Azure Functions project?

Tags: azure, .net-core, f#, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

In simple F# Azure Functions project host.json not being copied to output in F# Azure Functions project (same local.settings.json) even if specified so in fsharp-azure-functions-signalr-problem.fsproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>fsharp_azure_functions_signalr_problem</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="negotiate.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Same C# project have no such problem.

Example of my F# project you can `git clone https://github.com/ed-ilyin/fsharp-azure-functions-signalr-problem.git`

Without host.json file I have following error:

```
> func start
...
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'negotiate'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'connectionInfo' to type SignalRConnectionInfo. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
...
```

Comment: Do you test it on local or on azure?

Comment: Actualy both, after publishing without host.json, default and wrong one created. Error in my question is from local test.

Comment: You can check the compiled folder. If there is no host.json, manually copy the host..json file to this folder, and then use the zip deploy method to deploy the function to Azure.

Comment: Manual copy works and helps, but question is why this not happening automatically as it should be.

Comment: Please try to change the .fsproj file. I think it is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So manual copy to compiled folder can solve this problem. I have test the F#, it seems problem comes from your .fsproj file, the definition of host.json should look like this:

```
<Content Include="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

This work fine on my side.

Answer (score 2):

None Include works too:

```
<None Include="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

The problem is tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/8914).

C# projects by default include all files via a wild card. Thats why *Update* works. In F# no files are included by default (because file order matters). So there is nothing to update.